# Differentiation and Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\phi:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be increasing and left-continuous, with $\phi(0)=0$. Suppose on $(0,\infty)$ that $\phi$ neither
identically zero nor identically infinite. Then the function $\Phi$ defined by

$$
\Phi(s)=\int_{0}^{s}\phi(u)du,\qquad (s\geq 0)
$$
is said to be a Young's function (C. Bennett and R. Sharpley, *Interpolation of operators*, Page 265, Definition 8.1 ).

The authors give an example of Young's function $\Phi(s)=s^{p}$ with $\phi(u)=pu^{p-1}$, where $1\leq p<\infty$. I don't understand the $p=1$ case, that is, how $\Phi(s)=s$ can be a Young's function? For this case how is the condition $\phi(0)=0$ satisfied  ?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

$$\phi(u)=\begin{cases} 0 & u=0 \\ 1 & u>0 \end{cases}. $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand now.